# How to hide and show form text fields using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code, it hides some of the form textfields when the second value of drop down menue is selected.

The question is how can i edit this javascript code after i add more textfields to my html form that i want to hide and show based on the provided code below:

```
    <form id="form5" name="form5" class="wufoo topLabel page1" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" novalidate
action="#">

<header id="header" class="info">
<h2>Personal Shopper Order Form</h2>
<div>Place your order by filling this form</div>
</header>

<ul class="running">


<li class="total">
<output id="lola">
</output>
</li>


<li id="fo5li1" class="notranslate       ">
<label class="desc" id="title1" for="Field1">
Choose a plan
<span id="req_1" class="req">*</span>
</label>
<div>
<select id="Field1" name="Field1" class="field select medium" onclick="handleInput(this);" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" tabindex="1" > 
<option value="Lite Plan $0 per order" selected="selected">
Lite Plan $0 per order
</option>
<option value="Pro Plan $10 per order" >
Pro Plan $10 per order
</option>
</select>
</div>
<p class="instruct" id="instruct1"><small>Lite plan for order with a single item, Pro plan for order with up to 3 items per order.</small></p>
</li>



<li id="fo5li3" class="notranslate      ">
<label class="desc" id="title3" for="Field3">
Item #1 Name
<span id="req_3" class="req">*</span>
</label>
<div>
<input id="Field3" name="Field3" type="text" class="field text medium" value="" maxlength="100" tabindex="2" onkeyup="handleInput(this); validateRange(3, 'character');" onchange="handleInput(this);" required />
<label for="Field3">Must be between <var id="rangeMinMsg3">4</var> and <var id="rangeMaxMsg3">100</var> characters.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <em class="currently">Currently Used: <var id="rangeUsedMsg3">0</var> characters.</em></label>
</div>
<p class="instruct" id="instruct3"><small>Item name such as "iPad3 32GB wifi & 3G.</small></p>
</li>


<li id="fo5li2" class="notranslate      ">
<label class="desc" id="title2" for="Field2">
Item #1 Price
<span id="req_2" class="req">*</span>
</label>
<span class="symbol">$</span>
<span>
<input id="Field2" name="Field2" type="text" class="field text currency nospin" value="" size="10" tabindex="3" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" required />
<label for="Field2">Dollars</label>
</span>
<span class="symbol radix">.</span>
<span class="cents">
<input id="Field2-1" name="Field2-1" type="text" class="field text nospin" value="" size="2" maxlength="2" tabindex="4" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" />
<label for="Field2-1">Cents</label>
</span>
<p class="instruct" id="instruct2"><small>Item(s) Price as listed on the US online store.</small></p>
</li>


<li id="fo5li4" class="notranslate      hide">
<label class="desc" id="title4" for="Field4">
Item #2 Name
<span id="req_4" class="req">*</span>
</label>
<div>
<input id="Field4" name="Field4" type="text" class="field text medium" value="" maxlength="100" tabindex="5" onkeyup="handleInput(this); validateRange(4, 'character');" onchange="handleInput(this);" required />
<label for="Field4">Must be between <var id="rangeMinMsg4">4</var> and <var id="rangeMaxMsg4">100</var> characters.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <em class="currently">Currently Used: <var id="rangeUsedMsg4">0</var> characters.</em></label>
</div>
<p class="instruct" id="instruct4"><small>Item name such as "iPad3 32GB wifi & 3G.</small></p>
</li>


<li id="fo5li6" class="notranslate      hide">
<label class="desc" id="title6" for="Field6">
Item #2 Price
<span id="req_6" class="req">*</span>
</label>
<span class="symbol">$</span>
<span>
<input id="Field6" name="Field6" type="text" class="field text currency nospin" value="" size="10" tabindex="6" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" required />
<label for="Field6">Dollars</label>
</span>
<span class="symbol radix">.</span>
<span class="cents">
<input id="Field6-1" name="Field6-1" type="text" class="field text nospin" value="" size="2" maxlength="2" tabindex="7" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" />
<label for="Field6-1">Cents</label>
</span>
</li>

<li id="fo5li4" class="notranslate      hide">
<label class="desc" id="title4" for="Field14">
Item #3 Name
<span id="req_4" class="req">*</span>
</label>
<div>
<input id="Field4" name="Field14" type="text" class="field text medium" value="" maxlength="100" tabindex="5" onkeyup="handleInput(this); validateRange(4, 'character');" onchange="handleInput(this);" required />
<label for="Field4">Must be between <var id="rangeMinMsg4">4</var> and <var id="rangeMaxMsg4">100</var> characters.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <em class="currently">Currently Used: <var id="rangeUsedMsg4">0</var> characters.</em></label>
</div>
<p class="instruct" id="instruct4"><small>Item name such as "iPad3 32GB wifi & 3G.</small></p>
</li>


<li id="fo5li6" class="notranslate      hide">
<label class="desc" id="title6" for="Field16">
Item #3 Price
<span id="req_6" class="req">*</span>
</label>
<span class="symbol">$</span>
<span>
<input id="Field6" name="Field16" type="text" class="field text currency nospin" value="" size="10" tabindex="6" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" required />
<label for="Field6">Dollars</label>
</span>
<span class="symbol radix">.</span>
<span class="cents">
<input id="Field16-1" name="Field16-1" type="text" class="field text nospin" value="" size="2" maxlength="2" tabindex="7" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" />
<label for="Field6-1">Cents</label>
</span>
</li>

<li id="fo5li8" class="notranslate section      ">
<section>
<h3 id="title8">
Personal Information
</h3>
<div id="instruct8">Shipping address where your packages will be shipped to!</div>
</section>
</li>


<li id="fo5li9" class="date notranslate      ">
<label class="desc" id="title9" for="Field9">
Date
</label>
<span>
<input id="Field9-1" name="Field9-1" type="text" class="field text" value="" size="2" maxlength="2" tabindex="8" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" />
<label for="Field9-1">MM</label>
</span> 
<span class="symbol">/</span>
<span>
<input id="Field9-2" name="Field9-2" type="text" class="field text" value="" size="2" maxlength="2" tabindex="9" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" />
<label for="Field9-2">DD</label>
</span>
<span class="symbol">/</span>
<span>
 <input id="Field9" name="Field9" type="text" class="field text" value="" size="4" maxlength="4" tabindex="10" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" />
<label for="Field9">YYYY</label>
</span>
<span id="cal9">
<img id="pick9" class="datepicker" src="/images/icons/calendar.png" alt="Pick a date." />
</span>
</li>



<li id="fo5li10" class="notranslate  notStacked     ">
<fieldset>
<![if !IE | (gte IE 8)]>
<legend id="title10" class="desc">
Gender
<span id="req_10" class="req">*</span>
</legend>
<![endif]>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<label id="title10" class="desc">
Gender
<span id="req_10" class="req">*</span>
</label>
<![endif]-->
<div>
<input id="radioDefault_10" name="Field10" type="hidden" value="" />
<span>
<input id="Field10_0" name="Field10" type="radio" class="field radio" value="Male" tabindex="11" onchange="handleInput(this);" onmouseup="handleInput(this);" checked="checked"  
required />
<label class="choice" for="Field10_0" >
Male</label>
</span>
<span>
<input id="Field10_1" name="Field10" type="radio" class="field radio" value="Female" tabindex="12" onchange="handleInput(this);" onmouseup="handleInput(this);" required />
<label class="choice" for="Field10_1" >
Female</label>
</span>
</div>
</fieldset>
</li>


<li id="fo5li11" class="complex notranslate      ">
<label class="desc" id="title11" for="Field11">
Address
<span id="req_11" class="req">*</span>
</label>
<div>
<span class="full addr1">
<input id="Field11" name="Field11" type="text" class="field text addr" value="" tabindex="13" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" required />
<label for="Field11">Street Address</label>
</span>
<span class="full addr2">
<input id="Field12" name="Field12" type="text" class="field text addr" value="" tabindex="14" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" />
<label for="Field12">Address Line 2</label>
</span>
<span class="left city">
<input id="Field13" name="Field13" type="text" class="field text addr" value="" tabindex="15" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" required />
<label for="Field13">City</label>
</span>
<span class="right state">
<input id="Field14" name="Field14" type="text" class="field text addr" value="" tabindex="16" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" required />
<label for="Field14">State / Province / Region</label>
</span>
<span class="left zip">
<input id="Field15" name="Field15" type="text" class="field text addr" value="" maxlength="15" tabindex="17" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" required />
<label for="Field15">Postal / Zip Code</label>
</span>
<span class="right country">
<select id="Field16" name="Field16" class="field select addr" tabindex="18" onclick="handleInput(this);" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" >
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="United States" >United States</option>
<option value="United Kingdom" >United Kingdom</option>
<option value="Australia" >Australia</option>
<option value="Canada" >Canada</option>
<option value="France" >France</option>
<option value="New Zealand" >New Zealand</option>
<option value="India" >India</option>
<option value="Brazil" >Brazil</option>
<option value="----" >----</option>
<option value="Afghanistan" >Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Åland Islands" >Åland Islands</option>
<option value="Albania" >Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria" >Algeria</option>
<option value="American Samoa" >American Samoa</option>
<option value="Andorra" >Andorra</option>
<option value="Angola" >Angola</option>
<option value="Anguilla" >Anguilla</option>
<option value="Antarctica" >Antarctica</option>
<option value="Antigua and Barbuda" >Antigua and Barbuda</option>
<option value="Argentina" >Argentina</option>
<option value="Armenia" >Armenia</option>
<option value="Aruba" >Aruba</option>
<option value="Austria" >Austria</option>
<option value="Azerbaijan" >Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="Bahamas" >Bahamas</option>
<option value="Bahrain" >Bahrain</option>
<option value="Bangladesh" >Bangladesh</option>
<option value="Barbados" >Barbados</option>
<option value="Belarus" >Belarus</option>
<option value="Belgium" >Belgium</option>
<option value="Belize" >Belize</option>
<option value="Benin" >Benin</option>
<option value="Bermuda" >Bermuda</option>
<option value="Bhutan" >Bhutan</option>
<option value="Bolivia" >Bolivia</option>
<option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina" >Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
<option value="Botswana" >Botswana</option>
<option value="British Indian Ocean Territory" >British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
<option value="Brunei Darussalam" >Brunei Darussalam</option>
<option value="Bulgaria" >Bulgaria</option>
<option value="Burkina Faso" >Burkina Faso</option>
<option value="Burundi" >Burundi</option>
<option value="Cambodia" >Cambodia</option>
<option value="Cameroon" >Cameroon</option>
<option value="Cape Verde" >Cape Verde</option>
<option value="Cayman Islands" >Cayman Islands</option>
<option value="Central African Republic" >Central African Republic</option>
<option value="Chad" >Chad</option>
<option value="Chile" >Chile</option>
<option value="China" >China</option>
<option value="Colombia" >Colombia</option>
<option value="Comoros" >Comoros</option>
<option value="Democratic Republic of the Congo" >Democratic Republic of the Congo</option>
<option value="Republic of the Congo" >Republic of the Congo</option>
<option value="Cook Islands" >Cook Islands</option>
<option value="Costa Rica" >Costa Rica</option>
<option value="C&ocirc;te d'Ivoire" >C&ocirc;te d'Ivoire</option>
<option value="Croatia" >Croatia</option>
<option value="Cuba" >Cuba</option>
<option value="Cyprus" >Cyprus</option>
<option value="Czech Republic" >Czech Republic</option>
<option value="Denmark" >Denmark</option>
<option value="Djibouti" >Djibouti</option>
<option value="Dominica" >Dominica</option>
<option value="Dominican Republic" >Dominican Republic</option>
<option value="East Timor" >East Timor</option>
<option value="Ecuador" >Ecuador</option>
<option value="Egypt" >Egypt</option>
<option value="El Salvador" >El Salvador</option>
<option value="Equatorial Guinea" >Equatorial Guinea</option>
<option value="Eritrea" >Eritrea</option>
<option value="Estonia" >Estonia</option>
<option value="Ethiopia" >Ethiopia</option>
<option value="Faroe Islands" >Faroe Islands</option>
<option value="Fiji" >Fiji</option>
<option value="Finland" >Finland</option>
<option value="Gabon" >Gabon</option>
<option value="Gambia" >Gambia</option>
<option value="Georgia" >Georgia</option>
<option value="Germany" >Germany</option>
<option value="Ghana" >Ghana</option>
<option value="Gibraltar" >Gibraltar</option>
<option value="Greece" >Greece</option>
<option value="Grenada" >Grenada</option>
<option value="Guatemala" >Guatemala</option>
<option value="Guinea" >Guinea</option>
<option value="Guinea-Bissau" >Guinea-Bissau</option>
<option value="Guyana" >Guyana</option>
<option value="Haiti" >Haiti</option>
<option value="Honduras" >Honduras</option>
<option value="Hong Kong" >Hong Kong</option>
<option value="Hungary" >Hungary</option>
<option value="Iceland" >Iceland</option>
<option value="Indonesia" >Indonesia</option>
<option value="Iran" >Iran</option>
<option value="Iraq" >Iraq</option>
<option value="Ireland" >Ireland</option>
<option value="Israel" >Israel</option>
<option value="Italy" >Italy</option>
<option value="Jamaica" >Jamaica</option>
<option value="Japan" >Japan</option>
<option value="Jordan" >Jordan</option>
<option value="Kazakhstan" >Kazakhstan</option>
<option value="Kenya" >Kenya</option>
<option value="Kiribati" >Kiribati</option>
<option value="North Korea" >North Korea</option>
<option value="South Korea" >South Korea</option>
<option value="Kuwait" >Kuwait</option>
<option value="Kyrgyzstan" >Kyrgyzstan</option>
<option value="Laos" >Laos</option>
<option value="Latvia" >Latvia</option>
<option value="Lebanon" >Lebanon</option>
<option value="Lesotho" >Lesotho</option>
<option value="Liberia" >Liberia</option>
<option value="Libya" >Libya</option>
<option value="Liechtenstein" >Liechtenstein</option>
<option value="Lithuania" >Lithuania</option>
<option value="Luxembourg" >Luxembourg</option>
<option value="Macedonia" >Macedonia</option>
<option value="Madagascar" >Madagascar</option>
<option value="Malawi" >Malawi</option>
<option value="Malaysia" >Malaysia</option>
<option value="Maldives" >Maldives</option>
<option value="Mali" >Mali</option>
<option value="Malta" >Malta</option>
<option value="Marshall Islands" >Marshall Islands</option>
<option value="Mauritania" >Mauritania</option>
<option value="Mauritius" >Mauritius</option>
<option value="Mexico" >Mexico</option>
<option value="Micronesia" >Micronesia</option>
<option value="Moldova" >Moldova</option>
<option value="Monaco" >Monaco</option>
<option value="Mongolia" >Mongolia</option>
<option value="Montenegro" >Montenegro</option>
<option value="Morocco" >Morocco</option>
<option value="Mozambique" >Mozambique</option>
<option value="Myanmar" >Myanmar</option>
<option value="Namibia" >Namibia</option>
<option value="Nauru" >Nauru</option>
<option value="Nepal" >Nepal</option>
<option value="Netherlands" >Netherlands</option>
<option value="Netherlands Antilles" >Netherlands Antilles</option>
<option value="Nicaragua" >Nicaragua</option>
<option value="Niger" >Niger</option>
<option value="Nigeria" >Nigeria</option>
<option value="Norway" >Norway</option>
<option value="Oman" >Oman</option>
<option value="Pakistan" >Pakistan</option>
<option value="Palau" >Palau</option>
<option value="Palestine" >Palestine</option>
<option value="Panama" >Panama</option>
<option value="Papua New Guinea" >Papua New Guinea</option>
<option value="Paraguay" >Paraguay</option>
<option value="Peru" >Peru</option>
<option value="Philippines" >Philippines</option>
<option value="Poland" >Poland</option>
<option value="Portugal" >Portugal</option>
<option value="Puerto Rico" >Puerto Rico</option>
<option value="Qatar" >Qatar</option>
<option value="Romania" >Romania</option>
<option value="Russia" >Russia</option>
<option value="Rwanda" >Rwanda</option>
<option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis" >Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
<option value="Saint Lucia" >Saint Lucia</option>
<option value="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines" >Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
<option value="Samoa" >Samoa</option>
<option value="San Marino" >San Marino</option>
<option value="Sao Tome and Principe" >Sao Tome and Principe</option>
<option value="Saudi Arabia" >Saudi Arabia</option>
<option value="Senegal" >Senegal</option>
<option value="Serbia" >Serbia</option>
<option value="Seychelles" >Seychelles</option>
<option value="Sierra Leone" >Sierra Leone</option>
<option value="Singapore" >Singapore</option>
<option value="Slovakia" >Slovakia</option>
<option value="Slovenia" >Slovenia</option>
<option value="Solomon Islands" >Solomon Islands</option>
<option value="Somalia" >Somalia</option>
<option value="South Africa" >South Africa</option>
<option value="Spain" >Spain</option>
<option value="Sri Lanka" >Sri Lanka</option>
<option value="Sudan" >Sudan</option>
<option value="Suriname" >Suriname</option>
<option value="Swaziland" >Swaziland</option>
<option value="Sweden" >Sweden</option>
<option value="Switzerland" >Switzerland</option>
<option value="Syria" >Syria</option>
<option value="Taiwan" >Taiwan</option>
<option value="Tajikistan" >Tajikistan</option>
<option value="Tanzania" >Tanzania</option>
<option value="Thailand" >Thailand</option>
<option value="Togo" >Togo</option>
<option value="Tonga" >Tonga</option>
<option value="Trinidad and Tobago" >Trinidad and Tobago</option>
<option value="Tunisia" >Tunisia</option>
<option value="Turkey" >Turkey</option>
<option value="Turkmenistan" >Turkmenistan</option>
<option value="Tuvalu" >Tuvalu</option>
<option value="Uganda" >Uganda</option>
<option value="Ukraine" >Ukraine</option>
<option value="United Arab Emirates" >United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands" >United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
<option value="Uruguay" >Uruguay</option>
<option value="Uzbekistan" >Uzbekistan</option>
<option value="Vanuatu" >Vanuatu</option>
<option value="Vatican City" >Vatican City</option>
<option value="Venezuela" >Venezuela</option>
<option value="Vietnam" >Vietnam</option>
<option value="Virgin Islands, British" >Virgin Islands, British</option>
<option value="Virgin Islands, U.S." >Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
<option value="Yemen" >Yemen</option>
<option value="Zambia" >Zambia</option>
<option value="Zimbabwe" >Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
<label for="Field16">Country</label>
</span>
</div>
</li>



<li id="fo5li17" class="notranslate      ">
<label class="desc" id="title17" for="Field17">
Email
</label>
<div>
<input id="Field17" name="Field17" type="email" spellcheck="false" class="field text medium" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="19" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" /> 
</div>
</li>





<li class="buttons ">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="currentPage" id="currentPage" value="hrrPrWZVP1AZJEJQzZtacb98R0HanwMV1y1wuBeO5wuslashRLQ8=" />

                    <input id="saveForm" name="saveForm" class="btTxt submit" 
    type="submit" value="Submit"
 onmousedown="doSubmitEvents();" />


<a href="https://master.wufoo.com/forms/m7p0x3/def/field1=shopandship.wufoo.com/forms/personal-shopper-order-form/"
target="_blank"
style="font-size:85% !important;visibility:visible !important;display:inline !important;
background:none !important;border:none !important;color:blue !important;
text-indent:0 !important;text-decoration:underline !important;position:static !important;
margin:0 !important;padding:0 !important;overflow:none !important
width:auto !important;height:auto !important;">Report Abuse</a>
</div>
</li>

<li class="hide">
<label for="comment">Do Not Fill This Out</label>
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="1" cols="1"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" id="idstamp" name="idstamp" value="2kFNZeuYuz6lYe9uHWYSc2f1+Ee+ilanB5I5soK26Ek=" />
<input type="hidden" id="stats" name="stats" value="{&quot;errors&quot;:0,&quot;startTime&quot;:0,&quot;endTime&quot;:0,&quot;referer&quot;:null}" />
<input type="hidden" id="clickOrEnter" name="clickOrEnter" value="" />
</li>
</ul>
</form>







   <script>
__RULES = {"Field1":[{"RuleId":"36","Type":"Hide","Setting":{"FieldName":"4","FieldTypes":{"1":"select"}},"FormId":"5","MatchType":"any","Conditions":[{"ConditionId":"60","FieldName":"1","Filter":"is","Value":"Lite Plan $0 per order","ReportId":"5","RuleId":"36"}]},{"RuleId":"37","Type":"Hide","Setting":{"FieldName":"6","FieldTypes":{"1":"select"}},"FormId":"5","MatchType":"any","Conditions":[{"ConditionId":"61","FieldName":"1","Filter":"is","Value":"Lite Plan $0 per order","ReportId":"5","RuleId":"37"}]}]};
__ENTRY = [];
__PRICES = {"ShowRunningTotal":true,"BasePrice":"0.00","Currency":"&#36;","Decimals":2,"BasePriceName":"Pre\u00e7o base","TotalText":"Total","MerchantFields":[{"Title":"Choose a plan","Typeof":"select","ColumnId":"1","Price":"0","ChoicesText":"0","Choices":{"369":{"ColumnId":"1","ChoiceId":"369","Choice":"Lite Plan $0 per order","Price":"0","Score":1},"370":{"ColumnId":"1","ChoiceId":"370","Choice":"Pro Plan $10 per order","Price":"10","Score":2}},"DisplaySetting":""},{"Title":"Item #1 Price","Typeof":"money","ColumnId":"2","Price":"1","ChoicesText":"0","DisplaySetting":""},{"Title":"Item #2 Price","Typeof":"money","ColumnId":"6","Price":"1","ChoicesText":"0","DisplaySetting":""}],"BasePriceText":"Pre\u00e7o base"};

</script>
```

The magic code is under Rules in the java script code, how can i add this functionality to new text field to the form?

Comment: You should post just the relevant part of the code, i.e. the JavaScript code, the HTML of the dropdown and the textfields. It's really hard to figure out what your problem actually is if you post such a big bunch of code. As well it would be nice to know what you have already tried on your own.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery's change function and hide / show whatever you want depending on the selected value.
My example checks which option was selected, the first adds a new button that has a click event
the second option adds another button and click event to hide all buttons. I hope this is useful, this is only my second attempt on stackoverflow to assist.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Using Functions</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("select").change(function () {
        var value = $('#Field1 option:selected').val();
        if(value=='Lite Plan $0 per order'){
            alert("Selected value= " + value );
            $('div').append(value+'<button type="button">change again</button>');
            $('button').click(function(){
                $('#Field1').hide().fadeOut(3000);
                $('#Field1').fadeIn();
            });
        }
        else{
            alert("other value= " + value ); 
            $('div').append(value+'<button type="button">change again</button>');
            $('button').click(function(){
                $('button').hide();
            });
        }
      });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <select id="Field1" name="Field1" class="field select medium" > 
        <option></option>
            <option>
            Lite Plan $0 per order
            </option>
            <option>
            Pro Plan $10 per order
        </option>
    </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

enter code here
```